# Out of gas when trying to deploy UniswapV2Router02 locally in Hardhat

Tags: uniswap, hardhat

When I try to deploy the [UniswapV2Router02 contract](https://github.com/Uniswap/v2-periphery/blob/master/contracts/UniswapV2Router02.sol) locally in Hardhat, I get the following error:

```
ProviderError: Transaction ran out of gas
```

[A similar question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/94621/uniswap-router-deployment-error-uniswapv2router02-cannot-create-instance-o) was already asked here, but I already

1. enabled optimization
2. use the appropriate compiler version.

Another solution is to simply leave out parts of code that won't be used. That doesn't solve my problem though, which is how to deploy the entire contract in its current form.

Any idea how to deploy the UniswapV2Router02 contract locally in Hardhat?

Comment: Where are you deploying it to? How much gas are you using?

Answer (score 5):

You should enable `allowUnlimitedContractSize` for your testing network in `hardhat.config.js`. I.e: Hardhat use "hardhat" network as default, you could simply add this line:

```
networks: {
    hardhat: {
      allowUnlimitedContractSize: true 
    },
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I want to remind you who occur the same error, this error also when the contract code size is larger than 24 KB, and it would warn when compiling to use hardhat.

You can use some tools such as [hardhat-contract-sizer](https://github.com/ItsNickBarry/hardhat-contract-sizer) in hardhat to check your contract code size.

If your contract code is too large, you should reduce the code size.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with truffle environment, I've made bigger gas limit on contract creation. Check this https://hardhat.org/config/.